# Azure yaml Pipeline hide password in script

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a python script for some automation that contains a username and password.
This script triggers in a azure pipeline on GitHub.
But the idea of pushing credentials to GitHub is not good so I would like to store those credentials in a variable so it can be used by the script when the pipeline triggers.
Just to make the example clear, the python script holding the credentials looks like this:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class$='visible-lg'] input#signInFormUsername"))).send_keys('<USERNAME>')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class$='visible-lg'] input#signInFormPassword"))).send_keys('<PASSWORD')
```

Those are the 2 important values that I would like to remove from my plain script and store them in an env variable so when the pipeline triggers the python script, will know from were to fetch those credentials.

Can anyone advice on the best practice for this kind of scenarios?

Thank you very much and if you need more info just let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend [github secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets). From the documentation:

> Secrets are encrypted environment variables that you create in an organization, repository, or repository environment. The secrets that you create are available to use in GitHub Actions workflows. GitHub uses a libsodium sealed box to help ensure that secrets are encrypted before they reach GitHub and remain encrypted until you use them in a workflow.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. I tried to use the GitHub secrets, but they are not reconized by azure pipeline. I get the error that `secret` is not reconized

Comment: If you have another issue, you should open a new question so people can see it. :-)

Comment: Yes I did open another issue related to this. is at this link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68483440/python-selenium-fails-to-run-in-azure-pipeline`